# Pass variable into .then async function

Tags: javascript

I am using firebase storage to build a gallery. I am working on getting the cover image for each gallery to display along with the name. I currently have:

```
var galleriesRef = storage.ref("gallery");

galleriesRef
    .listAll()
    .then(function(result) {

        // Loop through all the galleries
        result.prefixes.forEach(function(gallery) {
            imageRef = storage.ref(gallery.location.path + "/cover.jpeg")
            galleryName = gallery.location.path.split('/')[1]
            console.log("outside: " + galleryName)

            // Get the download url of the gallery cover image
            imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                // Pass in galleryName as well so I can construct html with name and url
                console.log("inside " + galleryName)
            });
        });
    });
```

I currently have two galleries "horses" and "macros", the output from the above code is:

```
outside: horses
outside: macros
inside: macros
inside: macros
```

This call is async so I need to pass galleryName into the function. Otherwise, when I reference it, galleryName is equal to the last gallery in storage. Is there a way to pass in the galleryName along with url into the function?

Thanks!

Comment: No need to "pass" anything, you can just access the `galleryName` in that function through closure.

Comment: "*when I reference it, galleryName is equal to the last gallery in storage*" - are you somehow iterating the storage? Please show that code. The `galleryName` of course needs to become a local variable.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the code to include the entire section. I iterate through each gallery to get the downloadURL of the cover image, and the name of the gallery.

Comment: is `galleryName` being implicitly declared as a global, or was it declared elsewhere in code?

Comment: @Klaycon `galleryName` is declared on the line `galleryName = gallery.location.path.split('/')[1]`. It was not declared elsewhere

Comment: @Bernard a declaration starts with `var`, `let` or `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to declare `imageRef` and `galleryName` as globals as they aren't needed anywhere except in that function and all it's doing is causing this issue for you.

`imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) { ... });` is scheduling a function to run some time in the future - however in the future your `result.prefixes.forEach()` loop has completed and `imageRef` and `galleryName` will both contain the *last* value iterated over by the time they're used to construct the html.

This is very easily resolved by capturing the values in each iteration by making it a locally scoped variable so that the `.then()` closure contains those unchanging variables and not ones being reassigned many times:

```
    // Loop through all the galleries
    result.prefixes.forEach(function(gallery) {
        let imageRef = storage.ref(gallery.location.path + "/cover.jpeg")
        let galleryName = gallery.location.path.split('/')[1]
        console.log("outside: " + galleryName)

        // Get the download url of the gallery cover image
        imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
            // Pass in galleryName as well so I can construct html with name and url
            console.log("inside " + galleryName) //will be same as outside
        });
    });
```